# Minor of an acyclic finite graph is acyclic as well

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, topological-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with no cycles. We want to either prove or disprove that any minor graph of $G$ is either acyclic or cyclic.

My idea:

If $G$ is cyclic, all connected components are trees. Choose one of these connected components, say $C$. A minor of $C$ can be obtained with vertex and edge deletions as well as edge contractions. Vertex and edge deletions cannot add any cycles. And I am quite sure edge contractions cannot do so either, but here I might be mistaken. Is it possible for edge contractions to add cycles to the component $C$?

We assume $G$ is finite.

Comment: Since you tagged this topological graph theory, I'll point out that edge contractions preserve the homotopy type and can't change $\pi_1$.